# Создание и инициализация объекта, в котором есть массив

Tags: java

у меня имеется класс `Computer`, в котором есть массив `computers` с длиной 5 элементов, а также конструктор, геттер и сеттер данного класса:

```
public class Computer {
    private int[] computers = new int [5];

    public Computer(int[] computers) {
        this.computers = computers;
    }

    public int[] getComputers() {
        return computers;
    }

    public void setComputers(int[] computers) {
        this.computers = computers;
    }
}
```

Как теперь создать 5 экземпляров этого класса в другом классе(`Main`), инициализировать их и вывести в `System.out`? Спасибо заранее за ответ.

Класс **Main**:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = {1,2,3,4,5};
        Computer computers1 = new Computer(x);
        computers1.setComputers(x);
        computers2.setComputers(x);
        computers3.setComputers(x);
        computers4.setComputers(x);
        computers5.setComputers(x);
        System.out.println(computers1.getComputers());
    }
}
```

... и тут выводится какая то чушь. мне кажется, я что то делаю неправильно. Помогите разобраться

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы передаете объект в метод `println` то у него неявно вызывается метод `toString()`. Этот метод определен классе `java.lang.Object`, соотвественно у каждого объекта есть строковое представление. Его реализация это строка вида `<ClassName>@<hashCode>`.

Если хотите что то более осмысленное, то метод стоит переопределить, например так:

```
public String toString(){
  return "Computer { computers=" + Arrays.toString(this.computers) + "}"
}
```

ps создаение `getters` и `setters` для публичных полей бессмыслено, тк и без них любой желающий может получить доступ к полям

Comment: спасибо! "создаение getters и setters для публичных полей бессмыслено, тк и без них любой желающий может получить доступ к полям" -  это понятно, просто пробовал разные варианты, забыл вернуть правильный

Comment: @Mikhail Пожалуйста, если ответил на ваш вопрос, отметьте его как правильный